# xcode/ios7: parallax effect with image clipped inside view

Tags: ios, objective-c, parallax

I am trying to implement iOS7 parallax effect. For this purpose I am using standard UIInterpolatingMotionEffect class.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

- Place photo inside UIView. Photo is larger than View's frame (on each side)
- Set View's size, and CornerRadius (with masksToBounds = YES)
- Move phone and watch parallax effect. Something similar as you are peaking inside hole :)

Almost every tutorial on web is simply moving whole view (by setting center.x) , but I don't know how to move content only (and clip it in same time). I have tried something, but obviously is not working:

Inside viewDidLoad I am doing next:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myView.layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"dog"].CGImage;
    _myView.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
    _myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"layer.position.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];

    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-80);
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(80);

    [_myView addMotionEffect:horizontalMotionEffect];
}
```

CALayer don't have addMotionEffect so I am accessing view.

Maybe my approach is not good from start, so if you have some other solution - it will help.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach here might just be to use 2 separate views.

1. The wrapping `UIView` you have now, sized to what you want with a corner radius and `clipsToBounds` set to `YES`.
2. a `UIImageView` with the image you want, added as a subview of the `UIView`.

Then, just apply the motion effect to the image view. This will keep the containing view static and achieve the keyhole effect you are looking for.